# Sidebar slides after adding bootstrap 5 library to html codes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Before Bootstrap library:

[image: before bootstrap library]

After Bootstrap library:
[image: after bootstrap library]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
}

body: body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

sidebar: .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  background: #11101d;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

sidebar-active: .sidebar .active {
  width: 240px;
}

sidebar ul li: .sidebar ul li {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

input: .sidebar ul li input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: #1d1b31;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

search icon: .sidebar ul li .bx-search {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
}

ul li a: .sidebar ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

ul li a hover: .sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #11101d;
  background: #fff;
}


}
ul li i: .sidebar ul li i {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Sinema Yönetim | Personel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="dashboardstyle.css"> -->

  <!-- ADDED BY COMMUNITY -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-content">
      <div class="logo">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
        <div class="logo-name">Sinema</div>
      </div>
      <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li>
        <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Arama yap..">
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">
          <i class='bx bxs-grid'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Anasayfa</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="İzleyici.html">
          <i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i>
          <span class="links_name">İzleyici</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="analiz.html">
          <i class='bx bxs-bar-chart-alt-2'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Analiz</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="filmler.html">
          <i class='bx bxs-film'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Filmler</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="bilet.html">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-ticket"></i>
          <span class="links_name">Bilet</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="salon.html">
          <i class='bx bx-chair'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Salon</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="profile-content">
      <div class="profile">
        <div class="profile-details">
          <img src="images/proflile.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="name-job">
            <div class="name">Aykuthan Kırcalı</div>
            <div class="job">Personel şefi</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <i class='bx bx-log-in' id="log-out"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-content">
    <div class="text">Sinema Salonu | Personel</div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

When I add the bootstrap library to the html codes, the sidebar shifts to the right, how can I fix it?

Comment: General advice: Build your site _after_ loading the library you intend to use. Adding it to an existing site is a recipe for problems. Since Bootstrap already provides [off-screen sidebar functionality](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/), I suggest you refactor to use it.

Comment: thanks for the advice i asked my first question sorry for being so unprofessional

Comment: Did you find what was the issue? is it fixed?